# Trigger selectionchange event from formArray control typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'm having a dynamic form with cascading dropdowns. When the page loads, I assign the values to the controls, but the `selectionchange` event isn't triggered.

**HTML:**

```
<div formArrayName="userDataAttributes" *ngFor="let other of userForm.get('userDataAttributes')['controls']; let i = index" class="form-group">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      {{i + 1}}.
                      <mat-form-field> 
                        <mat-select matInput placeholder="Select Data Attribute" formControlName="dataAttributeId" matNativeControl (selectionChange)="refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId($event.value, i);">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let attr of List1" [value]="attr.dataAttributeId">{{attr.dataAttributeName}}</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select matInput multiple formControlName="dataAttributeValues" matNativeControl>
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let attr of List2[i]" [value]="attr.dataAttributeValueId">{{attr.dataAttributeValue}}</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId(attributeId: number, index: number) {
    if (attributeId && attributeId > 0) {

      this.List2[index] = this.List1?.filter(a => a.dataAttributeId === attributeId) ?? [];
    }
    else {
      this.List2[index]= [];
    }
  }

  addUserDataAttributes(dataAttributeId: number, dataAttributeValues: any ): FormGroup{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      dataAttributeId: [dataAttributeId],
      dataAttributeValues: [dataAttributeValues]
    });
  }


bindValuesToDynamicForm(){
array: any=[{
dataAttributeId: 1,
dataAttributeValues: "4,5"},
{
dataAttributeId: 2,
dataAttributeValues: "2,3"}]

    array.forEach((x,i)=>{ (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('userDataAttributes')).push(this.addUserDataAttributes(x.dataAttributeId, x.dataAttributeValues.split(',')));
    })
  }
```

With the above code,the first dropdown `dataAttributeId` gets loaded correctly
but couldn't trigger the `selectionChange` of that control so it refreshes the `dataAttributeValues` control and sets the value.

Tried,

```
  this.refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId(x.dataAttributeId, i);
```

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve this is to manually call the **refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId** method after you set the value of your **dataAttributeId** control. You can do this in your **bindValuesToDynamicForm** method where you are iterating over your array and setting the values.

Here’s how you can do it:

```
bindValuesToDynamicForm() {
  const array: any = [
    { dataAttributeId: 1, dataAttributeValues: "4,5" },
    { dataAttributeId: 2, dataAttributeValues: "2,3" }
  ];

  const userDataAttributesFormArray = <FormArray>this.userForm.get('userDataAttributes');

  array.forEach((x, i) => {
    userDataAttributesFormArray.push(this.addUserDataAttributes(x.dataAttributeId, x.dataAttributeValues.split(',')));

    // Manually call the method to refresh the List2 array at the current index
    this.refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId(x.dataAttributeId, i);
  });
}
```

After pushing a new group into your form array, the **refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId** method is called with the current **dataAttributeId** and **index**, which should update your **List2** array as expected.

However, setting the values for **dataAttributeValues** control won't be enough because the values from array are strings and the values in your **mat-option** are probably different objects. You need to find the correct objects from **List2[i]** to set as the values for your **dataAttributeValues** control.

To set the correct values, you might need to modify your **addUserDataAttributes** method to find the correct objects from **List2[i]** to set as the default values for your **dataAttributeValues** control. You would do this after the **List2[i]** array is populated by the **refreshUserDataAttributeValuesByAttrId** method.

Here is a rough idea of how you might do this:

```
addUserDataAttributes(dataAttributeId: number, dataAttributeValues: any, index: number): FormGroup {
  // Find the correct objects from List2 to set as the default values
  const correctDataAttributeValues = this.List2[index]?.filter(attr => dataAttributeValues.includes(attr.dataAttributeValueId)) || [];
  
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    dataAttributeId: [dataAttributeId],
    dataAttributeValues: [correctDataAttributeValues]
  });
}
```

In your **bindValuesToDynamicForm** method, update the call to **addUserDataAttributes** to pass the index as well:

```
userDataAttributesFormArray.push(this.addUserDataAttributes(x.dataAttributeId, x.dataAttributeValues.split(','), i));
```